# Symbolic evaluation fails because it exceeds $RecursionLimit

Tags: evaluation

I am trying to perform a simple arithmetic in complex algebra.

```
       a := Subscript[a, 1] + I*Subscript[a, 2];
       b := Subscript[b, 1] + I*Subscript[b, 2];
       r[z_] := a/(b - z) + a\[Conjugate]/(b\[Conjugate] - z);
```

when I try to evaluate r[0], mathematica gives me the following message

```
       $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
```

I was expecting something like the following

```
       2*Re[a/b] = 2 (a_1 * b_1 + a_2 * b_2)/(b_1 ^2 + b_2 ^2)
```

Could someone please point out where I did mess up?

Comment: `Subscript` is a function too so Mathematica tries to evaluate the value of `a` ad infinitum inside it. Just change them to `a1` and `a2` for example. The same applies to `b`.

Comment: unbelievable, it worked. and i have been trying to understand what is going on for an hour. How come subscript is a function, that makes no sense at all. I cannot define a variable a_1 ? 
in any case, thank you so much @ Spawn1701D

Comment: At Mathematica every object is a function, that gives incredible power but it comes with a cost ... If you really need to have the subscripts, use ToString[Subscript[a, 1], TraditionalForm] when defining a and b. But make sure that you have cleared any previous values of them. And use `=` instead of `:=`.

Comment: thanks a lot, Spawn1701D

Comment: @Spawn, maybe write an answer to settle this? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this and it seems to work:

```
SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldAll];

a := Subscript[a, 1] + I*Subscript[a, 2];
b := Subscript[b, 1] + I*Subscript[b, 2];
r[z_] := a/(b - z) + a\[Conjugate]/(b\[Conjugate] - z);

r[0] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
```

I'm not really sure if this will work in a more general setting though.

Comment: Yes, that's a way around the problem (+1). And if you have other cases where `Subscript` needs its arguments evaluated, you just have to wrap those in `Evaluate`.

Comment: You just have to be careful around `Evaluate`. Especially with `Plot`.

Comment: I am not familiar with SetAttributes, and I will look into it now. Thank you @amr, Jens, and Spawn1701D

Comment: Yea the attributes can be surprisingly powerful. I recently found this out when I realized I could set `UndirectedEdge` to `Orderless` and thus have `Gather[{a <-> b, b <-> a}]` work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are powerful, but so is `With`, which is what I would use here.

```
With[{a = Subscript[a, 1] + I*Subscript[a, 2],
      b = Subscript[b, 1] + I*Subscript[b, 2]}, 
  r[z_] := a/(b - z) + a\[Conjugate]/(b\[Conjugate] - z)]


r[0] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
```

> ```
> (2*(Subscript[a, 1]*Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[b, 2])) /  
>     (Subscript[b, 1]^2 + Subscript[b, 2]^2)
> ```

This works because the `a` on the lhs of assignment is now distinct from the `a` on the rhs. Same goes for `b`.